# Drush install fails within Vagrant Puppet

Tags: drush, virtual-machine

I originally posted this on SO but thought I'd probably get more traction on the Drush side of things from you guys.

I've just gotten a new MacBook running Mavericks.

Unfortunately, I can't get our current project running on it.

We're using Vagrant and Puppet and during the `vagrant up` phase, I get a message telling me `err: /Stage[main]/Drush::Git::Drush/Exec[first drush run]: Failed to call refresh: /usr/bin/drush status returned 255 instead of one of [0] at /tmp/vagrant-puppet-1/modules-0/drush/manifests/git/drush.pp:32`

I can successfully `vagrant ssh` into into the instance but it's clear that Drush doesn't exist.

The only difference between the 2 systems is the operating system. All other files are from the same git repo and same branch.

Any insight would be welcome as this is a total ball-ache.

Thanks,

Steven

Comment: Could you post your drush module? Not sure it'll help as it works on another machine, but might be useful to see what it's trying to do

Comment: Sure - it wasn't myself that originally setup the Vagrant/Puppet config so I'm a little in the dark. Here's the drush.pp that's being referenced https://gist.github.com/stevieg83/def440cc4002640da17a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The drush.pp you are using is out of date.  I have used that one successfully in the past, but just a few days ago, Drush switched to using Composer to install, so running drush status will no longer download the console table.  Instead, you must run `composer install` after pulling Drush, or just install Drush via composer.  See the Drush project page for details.

The Drush Puppet module you mention will need to be updated to adjust for this change in procedure.

*Note:*  The drush.pp you are using would probably work if you told it to check out one of the Drush 6.x tags instead of using master (the default).  Haven't tried that, though.

Comment: Thanks Greg. It looks like that may exactly have been it. I don't think the other guys in the team have actually done a rebuild of the vagrant instance. I changed to branch 6.x and so far it looks to be working as expected.